# Setting MySQL time_zone info without shell access

Tags: mysql, timezone

I am working on a database which contains a number of "Date" fields. These dates need to be converted to UTC for some output, which I intend to do using
`CONVERT_TZ('theField','GMT','UTC')`.
However, the `@@global.time_zone` variable is not currently set (returns "SYSTEM" at present), and the timezone information table is currently empty. I believe this needs to be filled by running the `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` shell script (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/time-zone-support.html).

My problem is that I don't have any kind of shell access to the system in question, so it's impossible for me to run the `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` script. So I therefore have two questions...

1) If MySQL is using the "SYSTEM" time zone at the moment, is there any way to determine exactly what the system time zone is (remembering I don't have shell or any other access)?

2) Is it possible to generate the information in the MySQL time zone table by some means other than the shell script, i.e. entirely within MySQL itself?

Grateful for any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Having thought this through a bit more, I'm not sure question 1 even matters. The data is held in `Date` columns, so doesn't have a time zone associated with it. The info in the `time_zone` table is still required for the conversion from whatever tz I decide the `Date` fields represent (GMT, in this case) to whatever tz I want as output (UTC, in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can check what time zone you are using with:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

Setting the timezone:

```
SET @@global.time_zone = 'SYSTEM';
```

If you want to know the time zone of the system:

Windows:

Go to cmd and key in `systeminfo`

Linux:

```
date +%Z
```

Comment: Thanks - as noted in the question though, timezone is already set to `SYSTEM` but I don't have shell access to check what the system time zone actually is.